# Installing gambas3 from ppa

Tags: ppa

When using a Debian OS on my computer, I can download gambas3 from ppa:gambas-team/gambas3 every time I try with no problems. However when using a Ubuntu OS on the same computer using the same ppa, I get segmentation fault (cored dumped) every time I try. 
Notes: 
1) About one year ago I did not see this problem. gambas3 loaded with Ubuntu OS from this same ppa.
2) I have same problem when using ppa:gambas-team/gambas-daily
3) I tried ppa:nemh/gambas3 and got "No such ppa exists"
Can anyone explain why I am having this problem? Am I doing something wrong?
Vito Faraci